# Adding a Maven url in Android Studio Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository, local

I have the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://another.url/repo"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

How can i add a second maven url like this one: `"${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository"`? i have to keep the another url repository.

Comment: according to the forum i have to add another block of maven under the first block of maven:        `maven {
            url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository"
        }`

Comment: but is not working with my local maven repository

Comment: `Error:(25, 14) Failed to resolve: package:artifact:version`